# Get Weekday of 1st of Month - Android Studio

Tags: java, android

Im trying to get the weekday of the 1st of any month.
Ive tried this, but it doesn't give me the right number

```
mycal = new GregorianCalendar(2016, 10, 1);
Integer firstDayOfMonth = mycal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
```

2016-10-01 is a saturday and android studio answered with a 3.

April 1st 2017 is also a saturday, but i get 2. Not sure what im doing wrong here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> month - the value used to set the MONTH calendar field in the
>   calendar. Month value is 0-based. e.g., 0 for January.

So the date you are trying to get is the First of November.

Consider also to use pre-defined constants, like so:

```
Calendar mycal = new GregorianCalendar(2016, Calendar.OCTOBER, 1);
Integer firstDayOfMonth = mycal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
```